# Image transpose in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How do you transpose an image with RGB values? That is all pixels in line one should become pixels in column 1 and so on.

For a simple 1D case this is:

```
B=A';
```

I am after something like

```
img=imread('name.bmp');

R=R';
G=G';
B=B';
```

And then to have them assemble into a new image somehow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use short & simple [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) -

```
permute(img,[2 1 3])
```

Basically it exchanges the rows with columns keeping the third dimension intact, i.e. transposes each 3D slice. Advantage with this method would be that it would work even if you have 4 slices in the third dimension, for example for images with depth information usually stored as the 4th slice in dim3.

Comment: 3D transposition is the first practical use of `permute` that I saw... and I learned that from you. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng No more loops in IP! ;)

Comment: wow I didn't know `permute` could be used like that until today!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness you can use [imrotate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) and [flipdim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html) The order does matter though. Here we are flipping the columns (thats what the 2 is) and then rotating 90 degrees

`imshow(imrotate(flipdim(im,2),90))`

if we do the rotate first we would have to flip the rows (thats what the 1 is)

`imshow(flipdim(imrotate(im,90),1))`

Answer (score 1):

Since "Transpose on ND array is not defined" in Matlab, you can transpose each channel separately:

```
[r,c,z] = size(im);
tmp = zeros(c,r,z);
for k=1:z
    tmp(:,:,k) = im(:,:,k)';
end
```

Comment: this is slower than the other solutions proposed. Try to avoid `for` loops when possible