# Flip/Transpose image efficiently along y=x

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to flip an image along the y=x axis as so.

[image: Original]

[image: Flipped]

I've made this function to do what I want but I was wondering if there's a more optimised way to do this. The function I made is a bit slow when working with big images

```
def flipImage(img):
    # Get image dimensions
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    # Create a image
    imgYX = np.zeros((w, h, 3), np.uint8)
    for y in range(w):
        for x in range(h):
            imgYX[y,x,:]=img[x,y,:] #Flip pixels along y=x
    return imgYX
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply [`swap the first two axes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707563/image-transpose-in-matlab/29707606#29707606) that correspond to the height and width -

```
img.swapaxes(0,1) # or np.swapaxes(img,0,1)
```

We can permute axes with [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) as well -

```
img.transpose(1,0,2) # or np.transpose(img,(1,0,2))
```

We can also [`roll axes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) for the same effect -

```
np.rollaxis(img,0,-1)
```

[`We use the same trick when working with images in MATLAB`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707563/image-transpose-in-matlab/29707606#29707606).

Comment: this leaves the burden to the image library

Comment: @WalterTross OP seems to have tagged NumPy and is working with NumPy array and also NumPy tools - `np.zeros`, etc., if you are referring to NumPy library.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks, I had a feeling there were one line commands for this